# The google-api-php-client autoupload.php file is missing, anyone have a copy?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api-php-client

Here's the code, https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/

Here's the file that's missing, https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/autoload.php

I know it's possible to create this file with composer, but was just wondering if anyone has it available.

I'm also concerned that this alone might not make the software work, as I've tried to do it the manual way and the Class it can't reference is "GuzzleHttp\Collection" which is accessed in PHP with "use GuzzleHttp\Collection". I don't know how adding "autoload.php" will help referencing a file that's not part of the "google-api-php-client".

Does anyone actually have this software working in PHP, it says Beta?

Answer (score 1):

I found it using Google Cache,

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:992oyuQ76a0J:https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/autoload.php+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: I think it's time to make up a new fork ;-)

Comment: I need the same got 404 . If someone has forked please let me know .

Answer (score 0):

This file should be load from vendor directory

```
// include your composer dependencies
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```